# Pass a string value to Long

Tags: android, datetime

I have this date and time concatenated  into a string, Am I doing it right? because I want to pass the strDateTime to a Long type ( because its constructor is Long)
here's the code

```
public void DT(){
        seldate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.receivedate);
        newDate = seldate.getText().toString();
        timeChose = time1.getText().toString();
        final   TimePicker tp = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);

        strDateTime = newDate + " "+ timeChose ;
        DatabaseSource sched = new DatabaseSource(
                subject.getText().toString(),
                description.getText().toString(),
                strDateTime.toLong()
        );
        long result = dbHelper.addSched(sched);
        if(result>0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Add Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

P.S the selected date, I saved it to a preference key then get it and pass to the textview in the next activity (where I will create the event) then the time I have a edittext when clicked a timepickerdialog pops up then set the time to the edittext field itself.

Comment: What is the format of `strDateTime`?

Comment: String strDateTime

Comment: I meant is it in some format like `17-09-2016`? Show a sample date.

Comment: oh, yes,  (yyyy-MM-dd)

Comment: And you need to pass a timestamp into the function?

Comment: Yes I need to pass a timestamp to be sent to a constructor from another class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the date in `yyyy-MM-dd` format into a `Date` object.
Use `getTime` method to get the timestamp in milliseconds.

Try this,

```
String strDateTime = "2016-09-17 11:21 PM";

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm aa");
long milliseconds = 0;
try {
    Date date = format.parse(strDateTime);
    milliseconds = date.getTime();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// pass milliseconds to the method
DatabaseSource sched = new DatabaseSource(
        subject.getText().toString(),
        description.getText().toString(),
        milliseconds
);
```

Comment: I forgot the strDateTime is concatenated with time, so date and time are both concatenated in the strDateTime (string), so probably the format to be saved in the database is in the way like this (2016-09-17 11:21 PM) as DATETIME datatype in the database

Comment: So in the line of strDateTime.toLong(), is this right?? since the constructor from another class is like this (String,String,Long)?

Comment: hmm, I was able to save the data, but I can't retrieve the data. There's no sign or error it just the data won't load on the screen

Comment: no errors on this current issue BUT I'm not sure if the data was inserted correctly, because I can't retrieve the data. I'm using WHERE clause to retrieve the data and I use the DueDate (DATETIME) from the database , so meaning if I use a WHERE clause and I don't get anything it means the DueDate has no value. Now, I tried removing the WHERE clause, I was able to retrieve the data. However, I really need to use the where clause for the comparison such I use it this way WHERE DueDate LIKE "' + text + '"); <-- text is the string with value of the date ONLY

Comment: So the data is not inserted. So use a String instead of a long. Change the constructor to (String,String,String)

Comment: that is the first option I have done but I change to long because I use AlarmManager and pending intents, I'm trying to follow this code

http://clearosapps.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-alarm-manager-to-set-remainder.html

Comment: Use the code above for creating timestamp for `AlarmManager`.

Answer (score 0):

use this code `Long.parseLong("0", 0);`

here `"0"` is your string value, and `0` is default value (incase if string is empty or not in number format)